# Adding UTM grid (NAD83) with 1x1km spacing and label the grid lines?

Tags: qgis, utm, grids-graticules, nad83

I'm currently running QGIS 2.18.4 (the latest release).

I'm trying to add a UTM grid to my maps, specifically the NAD83 reference system for zone 15N, that hopefully can show UTM coordinates and with 1x1km spacing. Is there an easy way of doing this? I can't find a plugin for it, and I can't find any wms server with utm grids either.

I've gone to view > decorations > grid and enabled a grid at 1000m spacing, I think its correct, however, I can't get line labels for it.

I've searched for a while and I feel like I have a very specific question as I can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: Have you tried Raster > Projections > Assign Projection > (Search in that list of CRS and find the UTM zone).

Comment: Also, please read the GIS SE Tour before posting. You have asked multiple questions here. And there are other questions which answer your question as well - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38984/how-to-reproject-a-raster-file-in-qgis-with-datum-transformation

Comment: What do you mean by "line labels"? If I generate a grid as you state and click "Draw annotation" I get a grid with coordinates on the outside.

Comment: @ Vijay Ramesh I've never asked a question on this before.

Comment: @ Vijay Ramesh I've never asked a question on this website before. I'm not asking how to reproject a file, I'm trying to add a utm grid to my map.

Comment: @Spacedman Well I think you just solved my problem. I never even noticed that option when adding the grid. Thank you!
Now is there a way of changing the grid lines form solid to dashes? I can see how to change from a solid line to crosses but I can't edit the actual line or marker symbols.

Comment: [I think Vijay may have got confused with a different post]  Technically that is a new question newfrank, and should be posted as such, however you can change the line from solid to dashes in the same dialog by clicking on the line symbol > simple line > pen style > dash line

Comment: @JimT Thanks for the help. I didn't realize I could scroll down in that tiny window. All figured out. I appreciate the help!